# React Native Can FlatList items overflow the container?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is it possible to allow an item to overflow the container of the FlatList component?
In this example, the items in the FlatList are regular View components, that have a "popover" View component inside of them that I would like to display over the boundaries of the FlatList container.

[Here you can see the red boxes are clipped by the boundaries of the FlatList container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmDd5.png)

[This is what I'd like to achieve (red boxes (positioned absolute) are overflowing the boundaries of FlatList component)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QThCa.png)

My code

```
const Item = () => {
    return (
        <View // this view should be clipped and go inside the container
            style={{
                height: 55,
                width: 55,
                backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
                margin: 5,
        }}>
        <View // this view should display over FlatList boundaries
            style={{
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: -15,
                top: -15,
                zIndex: 40,
            }}
        />
        </View>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
            }}>
            <View
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'gray',
                    height: 120,
                }}
            />
            <FlatList
                style={{
                    flex: 5,
                    zIndex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                }}
                data={data}
                renderItem={item => {
                    return <Item {...item} />;
                }}
                numColumns={3}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try using the `overflow` style:

```
<FlatList
    style={{ overflow: "visible" }}
/>
```

Comment: This only works on iOS and not on Android.